# Doxygen: Nested structure naming

Tags: struct, doxygen, rtf

When doxygen is used to document a nested C structure like the following -

```
struct level0 {           
    struct level1 {             
        struct level2 {            
            int data1;            
        } var_level2a;           

        struct level2b {      
            int data2;       
            int data3;       
        } var_level2b;       

    } var_level1;     
};
```

The generated document the structure is named as this -

- struct level0::level1::level2a
- struct level0::level1::level2b

can we have simply the structure name be displayed (internally it may have the complete name with scope resolution '::' thing for referring) like this -

- struct level2a
- struct level2b

Please provide help. A quick response would be greatly helpful.

Comment: This is unambiguous, I believe. You can clearly see a structure in there.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
it is safe in ambiguity problem indeed.  
we have unique names for the inner structures so it will not conflict. but the problem is when doxygen reads the nested style of defining the structures it uses this '::' scope resolution. this makes the structure name long and confusing to normal readers who are not familiar with doxygen.
so our requirement is to have only the structure short names in the RTF document.

can this be achieved in any way? ... in @ref we can specify the link 'labels'; but this are auto generated links, on which we have no controls it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES` to `YES`?

Comment: Hi Doxygen,    

Thanks for your reply.    

Yes we tried that, but it is not resolving the problem. Actually I couldn't find out the changes it makes in the output doc if we set this HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES to YES or NO.

I, with my experience, see that for some cases the setting parameters of the config file do not always work as they say. I am using the latest version of Doxygen and the issue is there in both Windows and Linux version.

Since you created this tool, can you suggest if there is a stable (and having almost same features as the latest) version in which the above said thing will work?

Comment: If you find that something is not working as documented or expected, then please file a bug report for it in doxygen's bug tracker and include a self-contained example (config file + source in a zip or tar). I can only fix problems that I can reproduce. Doxygen has 200+ options, so it is impossible for me to test all possible settings.